# How to use HierarchyId in memory database with Entity Framework Core 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 8 the HierarchyId type was moved to the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Abstractions package.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#hierarchyid-in-net-and-ef-core

There is a conflict with EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.HierarchyId.
So, how to use HierarchyId with in memory database?

Comment: It is as designed. It is not recommended to use EF Core's several providers in the same project. If you have collision, call extension methods explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to fork the in-memory code in [efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId). Also upvote issue [#120](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId/issues/120). There are currently no plans to release an updated package, but if you're interested in maintaining it...